# OpenLayers: In what cases should I destroy the map

Tags: google-maps, memory-leaks, openlayers

OpenLayers.Map has three functions that look like being used for freeing memory:
destroy(), unloadDestroy(), updateSizeDestroy() ([link](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.unloadDestroy)).

Am I supposed to explicitly call them or not? From the description of "unloadDestroy", for example, it seems that it is already called by something.

I'm looking something similar to Google Maps' [GUnload](http://code.google.com/intl/lv/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GUnload), which is supposed to be run upon page unload event - is there something similar for OpenLayers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the source it looks like unloadDestroy is added as an event on map initialization, so unless you have a specific need to destroy the map before page unload you probably have nothing to worry about.

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js#L565